# What should I do with questions that ask about one solution vs another?

Tags: discussion, flags, scope

I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43990553/download-existing-folder-from-directory) where a user gives their problem and then gives two solutions in different languages, but then asks which one is the "best language" to use. The gist of the question is as follows:

> My problem is x.
>
> I don't know which language is best to do this with, but I have found a solution [here] and [here] for the respective languages. Could I have some insight on this?

I assume this question isn't productive to Stack Overflow? What should I flag it as? The flag I raised was disputed.

Comment: probably opinion based unless there's some clear and unambiguous criteria for "best"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You might as well flag it as

> `primarily opinion-based`: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

since the user is asking the community which one is better. As we all know, everybody has their own opinion on which language is better. Therefore, we avoid these sort of question.

Comment: To be more concise:  that kind of question is *literally* asking for an opinion.

Comment: @Makoto Pretty much I guess